# How to make link from JSP to external URL

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to create link to external resource from my JSP page, but it always adds the servlet's name as a prefix. This is my page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="www.google.com">Link</a>

</body>
</html>
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8080/Example/example.jsp` and then press the link I get to the following URL `http://localhost:8080/Example/www.google.com` instead of `www.google.com`.

Please help me to solve it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to specify a protocol:

```
<a href ="http://www.google.com">link</a>
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you a lot! It works great! Can you please give just a short comment of explanation?

Comment: If you don't provide your web browser with a protocol, it will assume your link is referencing a path on the same server, but if you give it a fully specific http URL, there is no ambiguity for the browser to misinterpret

Answer (score 2):

try to insert the complete path https://www.google.com

Comment: the path you used was relative, if you linked an existing resource in example folder the way you did it would have worked

Answer (score 1):

As Mostafa answered, you need to add the protocol which is `http:\\`in this case.
(It could be `ftp://`, `https://`...)

Note that it is not specific to JSP but it is a pure HTML specification. The address you set is an ***absolute*** URL and in this case you have to mention the protocol but  you don't have to if the URL is ***relative***.

You can have a look [there](https://kb.iu.edu/d/abwp) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

Enclose link into form tag

```
<body>
<form action="" method="">
<a href="www.google.com">Link</a>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: No, the result it absolutely the same: `http://localhost:8080/Example/www.google.com`

Comment: have you gave value to method ? post or get. if not then try it out.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, but I really need to add a protocol: `https://` behind my url as @Mostafa replied.

Comment: @TalhaMalik A link (`<A>`) doesn't have to be included in a form. The is absolutely no relation. It is not a submit button!!!